# Complicated Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform

Let $t \in \mathbb{R}, k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then
$$
t^k \widehat{e^{-at} \mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{R}^+}}(t)(\xi) = \frac{k!}{(a+i\xi)^{k+1}}
$$
([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNq3e.png))

How to show this result ? I tried a IPP in the integral, but it does not succeed.

Comment: Can you show it for $k=0$?

Comment: k=0 it’s easy, but that’s not what I’m interested in here

Comment: There's also a formula $\widehat{t^k f(t)}(\xi) = i^k \hat{f}^{(k)}(\xi).$